# Trying to upload a file using ajax in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3, I want to upload a image file using an ajax form

My Index view code is:

```
 <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Save","Home", new AjaxOptions() { HttpMethod = "POST", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {%>
       <input type="file" /><input type ="submit" value="Submit File"/>
   <% } %>
```

and Controller code is:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save()
{
   ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
   return View("Index");
}
```

When I upload a file and click on the button, the ajax form is submitted, but i am getting a Request.File.Count of 0.

Comment: I don't think you can upload files like that. I think most asynchronous file uploaders use the hidden `iframe` technique. But ianae.

Answer (score 0):

Default unobtrusive ajax in mvc doesn't support uploading files. You need to use hidden iframe/plugin (flash, silverlight..)/html5 or combination of those.

Some scripts that might help you:

- http://valums.com/ajax-upload/
- http://www.uploadify.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the the plugins suggested by @Lukáš Novotný or else you can do the following

- Create an Generic HTTP handler uploadfile.ashx
- Post the data to the file(set the form action="yourpath/UploadFile.ashx"
- In the handler you can read the file as 
  HttpPostedFile uploadedfile = context.Request.Files[0];

Answer (score 0):

Here's my Action that manages the file uploads. Would work with most Ajaxy file uploaders. (I think)

```
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase uploadfile)
        {
            try
            {
                var dr405 = new DR405Service().GetDR405ById(new DR405DBContext(), DR405Profile.CurrentUser.TangiblePropertyId);
                var saveLocation = Path.Combine(DR405Service.SavePath + DR405Profile.CurrentUser.TangiblePropertyId);
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(saveLocation);
                if ((int)uploadfile.ContentLength / 1024 <= 15000)
                {

                    uploadfile.SaveAs(Path.Combine(saveLocation, Path.GetFileName(uploadfile.FileName)));
                    var file = new dr405files { TangiblePropertyId = DR405Profile.CurrentUser.TangiblePropertyId, FileName = uploadfile.FileName, UploadDate = DateTime.Now };
                    //dr405.dr405files.Add(file); 
                    //c.dr405s.Add(dr405);

                    db.Entry(file).State = file.FileId == 0 ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
                    //db.Entry(dr405).State = EntityState.Modified;

                    new DR405Service().Save(db);
                    ViewData["UploadStatus"] = String.Format("File name: {0}, {1}Kb Uploaded Successfully.", uploadfile.FileName, (int)uploadfile.ContentLength / 1024);
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewData["UploadStatus"] = String.Format("File exceeds 15MB upload limit.  Please reduce size and try again.", uploadfile.FileName);
                }
            }
                 catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    ViewData.ModelState.AddModelError("_FORM", ex.ToString());
                }

            return View();
        }
```